# Identify the connectors on those sensors

Tags: pcb, analog, raspberry-pi, connector, flexible

I'd like to know what is the name of the connectors in those devices. I'm trying to create a sensor for myself, and I think they are very practical when trying to add cables or clincher connectors.

The pins are 0.1" apart

[image: Flex sensor 1]
[image: Flex sensor 2]

Comment: How far are the pins apart? Measure it, or include a size reference in the photo. I'm guessing it's 0.1" or 0.2". What is the diameter of the pins?

Comment: The pins are 0.1 inches apart.

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen a name for these pins, probably because they wouldn't be a common distributor item.  Suggest emailing someone whom makes them or a big connector manufacturer like https://www.mill-max.com.

Comment: What do they plug into?

Answer (score 4):

These are sometimes called solder tabs, they are crimped and/or soldered. An example is [1-88997-2](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-88997-2/826861). Here is a page [containing multiple options](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connector-contacts/344)

This image may be a good reference:

[image]

View the [source](https://www.pololu.com/file/0J750/FSLP-Integration-Guide-13.pdf), it may be interesting for your applicaton

Crimping may require an expensive tool, but if you plan on mass production, it may be a cheaper process than soldering. You might find a manufacturer to crimp and/or solder it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think those are called crimp Pin tins? I didn't know you could crimp them in a flexible pcb though. The crimping tool is expensive but not prohibitive.